# ConstraintSet how to clear constrainMaxHeight?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, constraintset

I have a `ConstraintLayout` and I'm adding a maxHeight constraint by using `constraintSet.constrainMaxHeight(R.id.recyclerView, (Utils.getScreenHeight() / 2.2).toInt())`

Later in my excecution I need to remove this max height constraint, so I do:

```
constraintSet.connect(R.id.recyclerView, TOP, PARENT, TOP)
constraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.recyclerView, MATCH_CONSTRAINT)
constraintSet.constrainMaxHeight(R.id.liveFeedRecyclerView, UNSET)
```

However, my recyclerView still has the "max height" assigned to it.
What is the proper way of unsetting the max height constraint and setting my view's height to Match Constraint?

P.S.: All the Constant values are the constants found in the `ConstraintSet` class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *ConstraintLayout* defaults the max height to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (decimal value is 2147483647), so try using that instead of `UNSET` which is -1.

[image]

Comment: Nice find, thank you! I'll try it out and let you know!